# How to like search a string values against an ​ array values ​in typeorm

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

my typeorm entity is

```
@Entity()
export class Temp {
    @Column()
    content: string
}
```

And the entity have a value like this

| content |
| --- |
| A, B, C |

At this time, I want query in typeorm this values ['A', 'D']

If the array have a duplicate value, ex) ['A', 'D']
The query must find entity

But if the array don't have duplicate value, ex) ['D', 'F']
The query must don't find entity

How to do this?

I try this code

```
database.find({
where: {content:In(['A', 'D'])
})
```

The case can find only 'A' or 'D' values
But the value is 'A,B,C'

ah! Additionally, there are more than 5 columns like 'content column'.
In the entity.

And the columns must && search

```
database.find({
where: {
content:In(['A', 'D']),
content1:In(['A1', 'D1'])
content2:In(['A3', 'D5'])
...
})
```